# SEO -- Useful URL Separators?

Tags: seo

I am trying to figure out if

1) using periods in my domain are better than not using any sort of separator.

2) using too many keywords in a URL is a bad thing (the user will never have to remember this url)

i.e.

If I want to enhance my SEO for mainly a baseball trivia app, but also wanted to show up in results for home run and pitcher:

Is it better to do a) baseballtrivia.homerun.pitcher or b) baseball.trivia.home.run.pitcher

Also, if I want to enhance my SEO:

Is it better to do a) baseballtrivia or baseballtrivia.homerun.pitcher (will the extra words at the end hurt my SEO chances)

Thanks!

Comment: I may be missing something, but how are you using what looks like subdomains for each page?

Comment: Im essentially trying to figure out if too many keywords distort the Google rankings, and if separating all words by periods or hyphens is better than not separating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO, not programming related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periods are (probably) not the best way to go, I would recommend dashes (-). Periods are used to to indicate file extension, and in the past, Google used this as an SEO indicator (.html ranked more highly). While this is no longer the case, a negative penalty still may be in place (.pitcher, not being a common filetype). In all likelihood, Google no longer uses this as an indicator, but other SEs might, so it's worth bearing in mind.

The more keywords you include in an URL, the less weight each is given. For that reason, it is often best to focus on the more refined keywords. Note also that Google checks for overuse of SEO, and in fact penalises websites that use an unnatural amount of keywords. I would suggest:

```
http://example.org/baseball-trivia/home-run
```

Comment: Just curious...if periods were my only option (let's say dashes didn't exist)...if my SEO phrase was "baseball trivia" would it be better to separate baseball and trivia by doing "baseball.trivia", or would it be better to just do baseball trivia (once again assuming that i could not use dashes.

Comment: Are periods your only option? If so - I  separate them with periods. Spaces would probably treat the terms as line keyword. But that's a different argument - do you want to rank highly for "baseball trivia" or for "baseball" AND "trivia"? That is something to consider when grouping your keywords. Ultimately, realise that Google is clever enough not to hold too much sway on the difference between "baseball trivia" and "baseball.trivia" - its your content that will drive your rankings up

Comment: Periods, or no spacing are my only options.I would want to rank highly for PRIMARILY baseball trivia, but also home run trivia secondarily. So if periods were my only option, would it be better to do baseball.trivia.homerun, or will that take away from my primary search ranking? I see what you are saying, I just want to verify we are on the same page

Comment: I would suggest baseball.trivia.home run too, although I would hazard a guess that the different between that and "baseballtrivia.homeruntrivia" would be miniscule

Comment: Great! Thanks for your timely responses and knowledge.

Comment: You might also want to consider underscores ('_')as a separator as, like dashes, they are rendered as spaces. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Google syas, "Consider using punctuation in your URLs. The URL http://www.example.com/green-dress.html is much more useful to us than http://www.example.com/greendress.html. We recommend that you use hyphens (-) instead of underscores (_) in your URLs."

in [this help page for webmasters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using full stops in your URL's. Reading [Googles URL Structure guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329) states that you should use hyphens in your URL's to separate keywords. Using too many keywords will impact your pages credibility also.

Comment: Lee, thanks for the advice. But what would a full stop consist of? Is that the period?

Comment: sorry yes...a full stop is a period

Answer (score 0):

Dashes are the best way to use as separators as Google gives preference to these types of URLs.  According to me Periods are not the best way to choose as these indicate file extension. And in the eyes of Google, overuse of keywords in the URL will be a bad impression.

Answer (score 0):

always use the root of the keyword. Means try to use the single word in url and do the site navigation structure. It helps to improve in ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Do not go with any suspicious separator which can be mistreated as extension indicator (.). In general, hyphen (-) is widely used as separator. Though there are no ready-made formulae, it is better to concentrate on less number of keywords in a single URL. And, you have to decide on the relevance.

My Recommendation:

```
    http://example.com/baseball-trivia-home-run-pitcher
```

Example from Google:

```
    https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues
```